# Setting up Libgdx project with git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, libgdx

I want to manage a Libgdx project with my friend. I heard i can do this using git. So... how do i do this with a libgdx project? I have tried doing it with dropbox - probably not a good idea, because it said that libraries are missing on friend's pc.

Martynas

Comment: Does your friend have LibGDX (and supporting libraries) files on their computer as well? You should be able to import the Java project like a normal project. Just upload the code to git like any other project

Comment: Yes, he does. Which files do i need to push to github repository? The whole project?

Comment: Yes, the whole project unless you do not want to give him access to certain parts like sesitive ID's. Then he pull the project.or he forks it and sent a merge request on occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use **github**, **Bitbucket** in which you can have private repository, i recommend you to install **GitTortoise** which it will make your life easier

start by creating an account and setting up your repository

you push all your project file so your friend could pull all the changes made in your whole project

with git tutoise all you have to do is right click on root of your project and click on push (after committing your change of course)

[image]

good luck

Comment: hi , did you try setting up git , did it work ? if any trouble leave a comment